# Normalizing size of multiple paths while maintaining their aspect ratio in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, resize, illustrator-scripting

I have quite a few irregular paths (approx. 200), each with a different bounding box. I want scale all of these to a similar size while maintaining their aspect ratio.

Before:

[image: before]

After:

[image: after]

Is it possible?

Comment: How would it work? Two images with different aspects can not be easily normalized, so would you: Normalize by height, ignoring aspect ratio? By width? Length of circumference? By bounding circle? By height and width (ignoring aspect ratio)? By BB area? Shape area?

Comment: I keep ratio and resize by height

Comment: And I set that I want to all path have 100point height but width keep aspect ratio. Also I can set ll of path to position x:0 y: 0

Comment: ok that's just not my idea of normalization. But fine.

Answer (score 2):

Select objects you want to fit by height and run:

```
#target illustrator

// ScaleToFitVerticalAxis.jsx
//
// Copyright (c) 2017 Janne Ojala
//
// Licence: https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT

visitObjects(app.activeDocument.selection, scaleByHeight, 100)

function scaleByHeight(item, targetHeight){
    var factor = targetHeight / item.height;
    item.height *= factor;
    item.width  *= factor;
}

function visitObjects(sel, func, opts) {
    for(var i = 0; i < sel.length; i++){
        func(sel[i], opts);
    }
}
```

Example:

[image: scaled to fit by height]

**Image 1**: Objects on first row are scaled to fit by height on second row.